# Datagrid cell color based on cell value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` with `ItemsSource` DateTable `DTableDay` from `viewmodel`. In `DTableDay` are cells with null content or with content "1". I want to set green color to cells with content "1"

my xaml looks like this

`<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DTableDay}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" >
                    <DataGridCell>
                        <DataGridCell.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="Content" Value="1">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridCell.Style>
                    </DataGridCell>
                </DataGrid>`

But if I run my app it throws an exception with

> "*Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and
>   modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.*"

Can anyone help me please? Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're doing the cell color changing correctly.  The exception you're seeing is probably the result of something you're doing in a different part of the code.  Can you look at the stack trace and see where what method it's being thrown from?

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own `DataGridTemplateColumn`. In this column you create a new `DataTemplate` using a simple `TextBlock`. You bind the `TextBlock`'s `Text`-Property to the property of object from the `DTableDay` collection. (In the example below I assume the property name of the binded object is `"CellValue"`.) Then you create a `Trigger` based on the `Text` property of the `TextBlock`.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DTableDay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding CellValue}">
            <TextBlock.Style>
              <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Style.Triggers>
                  <Trigger Property="Text" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                  </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
              </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
          </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>  
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few issues, first "DataGridCell" must be identified with DataGrid (i.e., "DataGrid.DataGridCell") otherwise any other elements in the DataGrid not prefixed with DataGrid. will be interpreted as a item, which means ItemsSource can not be bound again. Secondly, to set the cell style use the  [DataGrid.CellStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.controls.datagrid.cellstyle(v=vs.100).aspx) property.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DTableDay}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" >
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <!-- your style -->
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
 <DataGrid />
```